# Cuckoo Sandbox python errors after task submission

Tags: malware, sandbox

I'm New to Cuckoo Sandbox. Why am I getting this error? 
I don't understand. If there is something wrong, can anyone please explain how to setup Cuckoo Sandbox? My setup works very well before I submit any kind of malicious thing. I've been working on it for the last 5 days.

Thanks !

```
Cuckoo Sandbox 0.5
www.cuckoosandbox.org
 Copyright (c) 2010-2012
 Checking for updates...
 Good! You have the latest version available.
2013-01-12 18:42:42,738 [lib.cuckoo.core.scheduler] INFO: Using "virtualbox" machine manager
2013-01-12 18:42:42,935 [lib.cuckoo.core.scheduler] INFO: Loaded 1 machine/s
2013-01-12 18:42:42,936 [lib.cuckoo.core.scheduler] INFO: Waiting for analysis tasks...
2013-01-12 18:43:12,403 [lib.cuckoo.core.scheduler] INFO: Starting analysis of URL 
"http://gamerpocket.com/temp/images/qeqynu.jpg" (task=2)
2013-01-12 18:43:12,433 [lib.cuckoo.core.scheduler] INFO: Task #2: acquired machine cuckoo1 (label=cuckoo1)
2013-01-12 18:43:12,466 [lib.cuckoo.core.sniffer] INFO: Started sniffer (interface=eth0, host=192.168.0.100, dump path=/opt/cuckoo/storage/analyses/2/dump.pcap)
2013-01-12 18:43:20,308 [lib.cuckoo.core.guest] INFO: Starting analysis on guest (id=cuckoo1, ip=192.168.0.100)
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/cuckoo/lib/cuckoo/core/scheduler.py", line 318, in run
    success = self.launch_analysis()
  File "/opt/cuckoo/lib/cuckoo/core/scheduler.py", line 240, in launch_analysis
    guest.start_analysis(options)
  File "/opt/cuckoo/lib/cuckoo/core/guest.py", line 136, in start_analysis
    self.wait(CUCKOO_GUEST_INIT)
  File "/opt/cuckoo/lib/cuckoo/core/guest.py", line 59, in wait
    self.server._set_timeout(self.timeout)
  File "/opt/cuckoo/lib/cuckoo/common/utils.py", line 107, in _set_timeout
    if t._connection[1] and t._connection[1].sock:
AttributeError: TimeoutTransport instance has no attribute '_connection'
```

Comment: I think it is a bug in the beta release you can read relevant information from this link https://github.com/cuckoobox/cuckoo/pull/56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a bug in 0.5 that has been fixed in 0.5.1-dev. In theory it should only happen with Python 2.6, as we recommend using Python 2.7. You can manually apply this patch to fix it:
https://github.com/cuckoobox/cuckoo/commit/a6ae875f437e32d6b0f1af4107c0459f6fa7ecc3